# Net-snmp reloading working in strange way

Tags: net-snmp

I have placed snmp v3 configuration, createUser directive and rwuser directive in `/etc/snmpd.conf` path and while running snmpd i'm specifying it to read configuration from this path using `-c` option.(`snmpd -c /etc/snmpd.conf`)

Problem is when I placed createUser directive and send "killall SIGHUP snmpd" I can access with newly placed user, but even after I deleted the user from configuration file and send the signal still I'm able to access with the user. However if I reboot my system, user will be deleted and works fine.

Adding user works fine but deleting does not. any help will be appreciated.

I know I should place createUser directive in `/var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf`. But if I reboot the system placed entry will not be there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to put the `createUser` directive in the `/var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf` when the `snmp` agent is not running. Because this file is modified every time snmp agent starts and stops. So basically first stop the `snmp` agent (kill or service snmpd stop), update the `/var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf` with the `createUser` directive and then start the `snmp` agent.

To delete the user first stop the `snmp` agent remove the entry from `/var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf` and start the agent.